# SQLAlchemy query with variable class name and attributes

Tags: python, class, sqlalchemy

Hi I have a question about Python and a SQL query.

The class :

```
class person(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "person"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=False)
street = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=False)
```

Then I like to get all 'items' of a column in a list.

example:

```
streets = [person.street for person in db.session.query(Person.street).distinct()]]
```

This shall return a list of streets in the column streets.
But how can I make this attribute item variable?

I tried:

```
streets = [x.column_name for x in db.session.query((Class.attribute).distinct()]
```

I hope to find a solution that provides a list of items in the column, when we pass in a variable 'column-name"...

the problem:

x.column_name fails.... I learned in the documents that inside the list comprehension the 'x' is local to that list. If I change to x.street, then the street list is returned. Why?

How can I replace a well-known attribute to that class by a variable name?

Comment: I just tried `session.query(getattr(Person, "street")).all()` and it seems to work.

Comment: indeed it does. Thank you. It Was like the only option that did not cross my mind.